# Smooth page scroller not working for alt languages (i.e. altered URL structure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

I have a js that animates a smooth page scroll to another location when a more button is clicked.

It works, but not if another language for the site is selected. When a user changes language, say, to Spanish, the URL changes to `www.example.com/ES`. This seems to break the smooth scroll, which works on `www.example.com`.

Clicking the `more` link in Spanish seems to completely reload the page, in the scroll location, but without the smooth scrolling.

Here is my js. How can I include the alt language url in the smooth scroll?

```
(function($){

        $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Edit: For reference the script is enqueued in Wordpress' functions.php and the language plugin I am using is called qTranslate

Comment: Are you sure that script is loaded in the other page?

Comment: Yes it loads without error in the inspector. This is why I thought it must be in the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally got this to work. The language plugin I use requires that all supported non-primary languages have root url's succeeded by their abbreviation. e.g. a Spanish page might look like `example.com/ES/contact`.

The anchor I was using was accidentally redirecting a Spanish user back to the primary language because it was omitting the /ES/ part of the relative URL. I simply changed my anchor href element from `<a href="/#more"` to `<a href="[:en]/#more[:ES]/ES/#more[:]"`, to include the hooks that the language plugin uses to render different elements based on the language being used.

So the solution was in the HTML implementation and the javascript file I was calling was fine as it is.

Example at http://www.thelucyfoundation.com

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this part:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

This selector is choosing all of the  tags, try to add a class to to it. Something like this:

```
$('.more a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')
```

This function should be on you .js file not on the functions.php file. If you have a different laguage shouldn't affect the script that you have.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I tried that and it seemed to break the smooth scroll on both the default page and Spanish page.

Comment: Am I supposed to do something with the class that has been added?

Comment: Did you add the more class to the "more" button?

Comment: Yes, I used... `<a href="/#more" id="scrolldown" class="morescroll"> [:en]↓ More ↓[:ES]↓ más ↓[:]</a>` with updated js `$('.morescroll a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')`